# Where does Ubuntu get the default hostname?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, installer

My newly installed Ubuntu shows `lele-ThinkPad-X230` as its hostname. I downloaded debian-installer and ubuntu-installer (ubiquity) to see the code, but found nothing useful about this. Is this DHCP or some hardware database?

`lele-ThinkPad-X230`, split by dash: the first `lele` is my username, and the rest is the machine name (by Lenovo). So how does the installer get this when I input no hostname?

Comment: Great question, it freaked me out when it appeared to know things about my network.

Answer (score 2):

The Debian and Ubuntu installers both get their hostname through DHCP, as most DHCP servers provide this along with the lease.

For example, running the Ubuntu GUI installer on my Windows laptop suggests a hostname of "Ed-PC", as this was the name I assigned under Windows, and when I requested the DHCP lease.

As per the Debian installation documentation at https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch03s03.html.en#idp52296784:

> If the network you are connected to uses DHCP (Dynamic Host
>   Configuration Protocol) for configuring network settings, you don't
>   need this information because the DHCP server will provide it directly
>   to your computer during the installation process.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, this is where the Ubuntu graphical and alternative installer gets it's hostname - clearing all leases or not using DHCP causes the installer to use the hardware name.

Answer (score 1):

When I used Ubuntu I believe it used `lele-laptop`.

There's a debian package called `laptop-detect`.  It's yes/no test which is then used for extra setup for laptops.  Ubuntu would have used this for the '-laptop' suffix.

The manpage for laptop-detect references `dmidecode`.  `dmidecode` reports naming information for the machine like "Thinkpad X230" (and presumably enough information to decide whether it's a laptop).  It doesn't require a massive hardware database, it just relies on the vendor providing helpful information in the firmware (heh).

Putting the name of the hardware into the hostname could be a logical extension.

I think I've seen some Windows version setting it similarly but just using the vendor (e.g. Lenovo)... though AFAIK it could have been a vendor modification to the OS.

A DHCP mechanism is possible - if what you're seeing exactly matched a previous hostname of the laptop.  However it seems unlikely, and Ubuntu would have to implement it explicitly - I can't see *why* they would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the systems hostname by editing the file /etc/hostname
You should also edit /etc/hosts and update it if it appears there.

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but I just want to find out how they(debian-installer or ubuntu installer) get to guess it out.

Answer (score 0):

`hostname` package is responsible for creating `/etc/init/hostname.conf` file which inturn set the system hostname.This package is preinstalled on your Ubuntu OS(default).

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/init/hostname.conf
hostname: /etc/init/hostname.conf

$ cat /etc/init/hostname.conf
# This task is run on startup to set the system hostname from /etc/hostname,
# falling back to "localhost" if that file is not readable or is empty and
# no hostname has yet been set.

description     "set system hostname"

start on startup

task
exec hostname -b -F /etc/hostname
```

From `man hostname`

```
 When  called  without  any  arguments, the program displays the current
   names.

 hostname will print the name of the system as returned by the  gethost‐
   name(2) function.
```

Comment: How they get it right at the first time(installation)?

Comment: terminal holds on `dpkg` command. does this conf file show manual?